# When does it make sense to apply for another position at a company that previously rejected me after the first round of interviews?

Tags: recruitment

I applied for a position in a software company in Europe, and passed the first round but was later dropped from consideration. The company now announced they need to fill another position. When does it make sense to reapply for that position? **What should I consider before doing so**?

From one side, it is possible to view that the company has already evaluated  me. From another side, if I have lost against the competitor, that competitor will not apply again this time.

Comment: Closing reasons seem not obvious for me. Why job search is off topic?

Comment: The broader question is on-topic. I assume you're getting downvotes and closevotes because you worded this somewhat poorly. I also have to question what on earth you did to get "angry letters" when you reapply. Are you applying to the exact same job? Are you sure the company like you enough to consider you for new positions? A hiring process can have many rounds and only making it past the first interview won't count for much in most of them.

Comment: The standard generic phrase "we had better candidates" of no use to decide how much they liked me. Probably lots depend on the personality of the recruiter, hence the accepted answer I think is good.

Comment: I've edited your question but think it can still be improved further. I've left the currently last paragraph untouched but it's worded a bit strangely and you should consider rewriting that to clarify what you mean. The general question may still be tricky to answer but it's borderline on-topic in my view. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When job hunting my policy was to apply for as many jobs as I could. In this case though I would contact HR to see if I'm already being considered or should I reapply. Rather than just apply and risk wasting time I could be using constructively elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Unless they state that, you per Definition aren't desired, apply again.

You lost to a competitor that happens. You might have been number 2 or 100 you don't know unless you ask. So yes it makes sense they might even have considered asking you themselves.

This is why I think it is important to ask why you got rejected.